# Problems when switching ListView ChoiceMode on screen rotation

Tags: android

I am trying to build a split pane based on the [example code](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html#Example) provided at the end of the Android documentation about Fragments, basically a LinearLayout containing two fragments (all the details can be found in the above link):

- `TitlesFragment` to display a list of titles
- `DetailsFragment` to display the details of the currently selected title

My problem is that the following unexpected behavior happens:

1. I start the application in **Landscape** orientation: the titles list is displayed on the left and the details of the currently selected title (the first one at the beginning) are displayed on the right.
2. I select **item X** from the titles list: the title becomes highlighted since the ListView is set to `CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE` and its items implement the `Checkable` interface.
3. I switch to **Portrait** orientation (by rotating the device or emulator): as expected, only the titles list is shown and no item is selected in this configuration, because the ListView gets recreated and, by default, it is set to `CHOICE_MODE_NONE`.
4. I select **item Y** from the titles list: as expected, an activity showing only the `DetailsFragment` corresponding to the selection made is shown.
5. I switch back to **Landscape** orientation (here's where the unexpected behavior happens): the `DetailsFragment`on the right correctly shows the details of **item Y** (which was selected in portrait orientation) but the `TitlesFragment` still shows **item X** as selected (i.e. the one which was selected BEFORE the first screen rotation).

Of course, I would like that the last selection made in Portrait orientation was correctly shown also within the `TitlesFragment`, otherwise I end up with an inconsistent highlighting which shows item X as selected while displaying the details of item Y.

I post the relevant code where the ListView mode is changed (within 'onActivityCreated') and the selected item is set (within the 'showDetails' method):

```java
public static class TitlesFragment extends ListFragment {
boolean mDualPane;
int mCurCheckPosition = 0;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // Populate list with our static array of titles.
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, Shakespeare.TITLES));

    // Check to see if we have a frame in which to embed the details
    // fragment directly in the containing UI.
    View detailsFrame = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.details);
    mDualPane = detailsFrame != null && detailsFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore last state for checked position.
        mCurCheckPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("curChoice", 0);
    }

    if (mDualPane) {
        // In dual-pane mode, the list view highlights the selected item.
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        // Make sure our UI is in the correct state.
        showDetails(mCurCheckPosition);
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("curChoice", mCurCheckPosition);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    showDetails(position);
}

/**
 * Helper function to show the details of a selected item, either by
 * displaying a fragment in-place in the current UI, or starting a
 * whole new activity in which it is displayed.
 */
void showDetails(int index) {
    mCurCheckPosition = index;

    if (mDualPane) {
        // We can display everything in-place with fragments, so update
        // the list to highlight the selected item and show the data.
        getListView().setItemChecked(index, true);

        // Check what fragment is currently shown, replace if needed.
        DetailsFragment details = (DetailsFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.details);
        if (details == null || details.getShownIndex() != index) {
            // Make new fragment to show this selection.
            details = DetailsFragment.newInstance(index);

            // Execute a transaction, replacing any existing fragment
            // with this one inside the frame.
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.details, details);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            ft.commit();
        }

    } else {
        // Otherwise we need to launch a new activity to display
        // the dialog fragment with selected text.
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(getActivity(), DetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("index", index);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea about how to solve such issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know it is a bit late, but I have exactly the same behaviour. I'm testing the code in a real device, a tablet with API 16 installed. I put traces and could see that in `showDetails(index)`, the index is correct, but `setItemChecked(index, true)` doesn't highlight the correct title.

Answer (score 2):

Two years later, here I am working with the Fragment Layout sample from Android's v4 support library and I'm stuck with this exact same issue!

Here's the only fix I came up with that doesn't require using `CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE` all the time:

just add a call to `getListView().setItemChecked(mCurCheckPosition, true);` in the `onResume()` method of TitlesFragment. And... that's it!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should set the value of outState **BEFORE** you call super.onSaveInstanceState?

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt("curChoice", mCurCheckPosition);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Comment: Thank you again, but unfortunately that does NOT solve my issue.
It seems like the 'mCheckStates' field of the ListView is keeping the values that were set the last time that the 'CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE' was set, while any selection made while 'CHOICE_MODE_NONE' is set is discarded. Moreover, I noticed that if I keep the ListView in 'CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE' (by commenting out the 'if (mDualPane)' at the end of the 'onActivityCreated') the last selection is correctly saved and restored upon screen orientation changes. But I do not want highlighting in Portrait orientation... Any other idea?

Comment: It seems like my hypothesis was correct, i.e. selections made in 'CHOICE_MODE_NONE' have no effect on the 'mCheckStates' field of the ListView, which seems reasonable to some extent. My hypothesis is supported by the fact that I found the following (awful) workaround: if I add these lines of code:

    getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    getListView().setItemChecked(index, true);
    getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);

at the beginning of the 'else' of the 'showDetails' method, everything works fine. I'm sure there must be a cleaner solution...

Comment: I tested the sample code from SDK version 13 on a tablet running 3.1 and it worked fine. I did not get the incorrect behaviour. Maybe your emulator needs to be updated?

Comment: Actually the SDK version 13 code also sets the mode of the ListView to CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE all the time, not just for dual screen. I think you need to get the latest sample code. Yours is a bit different.

Comment: Can you better explain what exactly did you try? If you refer to 'Support13Demos' in the 'android-compatibility/v13/samples', I did not find any 'TitlesFragment' class within it (BTW, is it possible to run code targeted at API Level 13 on a tablet with 3.1, which has API Level 12?)... Nevertheless, in API Demos on 3.2 emulator, the App/Fragment/Layout example has the same incorrect behavior I described. I also updated my emulators to the most recent version a few days ago. Am I missing something?

Comment: PS: my first post (forgot to mention) referred to 'Support4Demos' in the 'android-compatibility/v4/samples' and had that behavior both on emulators (I tried on a 3.0 and a 2.2) and devices (I only have a 2.2 Android physical device at hand).

Comment: ~/android-sdk-mac_x86 $ find . -name  TitlesFragment.java 
./docs/resources/samples/HoneycombGallery/src/com/example/android/hcgallery/TitlesFragment.java
./samples/android-11/HoneycombGallery/src/com/example/android/hcgallery/TitlesFragment.java
./samples/android-12/HoneycombGallery/src/com/example/android/hcgallery/TitlesFragment.java
./samples/android-13/HoneycombGallery/src/com/example/android/hcgallery/TitlesFragment.java
~/android-sdk-mac_x86 $

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem on that code and as workaround I call `setItemChecked` on the `onStart` method:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (mDualPane) {
        getListView().setItemChecked(mCurCheckPosition, true);
    }
}
```

Or as LearningNerd said do it in `onResume()`

Answer (score -2):

If you place `android:configChanges="orientation"` in your activity tag in the manifest file, your app will ignore the rotations but still render the relevant layouts.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I was aware of such feature, but that is not the intended behavior. 

Indeed, I want the activity to be aware of the orientation change, since only title must be displayed in Portrait orientation, while titles plus details must be displayed in Landscape orientation.

Do you have any suggestion about how to achieve this?